# Trying to move tick mark and remove the X in the axis title

Tags: r

See code below.I created a vertical box plot for a data set then flipped it horizontally. The x and Y axis swapped. I want to be able to remove the "X" and remove the tick mark, but nothing I do seems to change the graph's appearance [image]

```
#install and load ggplot and ggthemes for plotting
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

#rename columns in Pulse.rate.2020 to be more informative
colnames(Pulse.rate.2020) <- c("bpm","grad/undergrad","season","year")

#Create box plot
a<- ggplot(Pulse.rate.2020, aes(x="", y=bpm)) + geom_boxplot(width=0.5)
a

#Apply tufte theme and range frame plot 
b<- a + theme_tufte(base_size=20) + geom_rangeframe()
b

#Set scale from 40 to 115 with an interval of 15
c<- b + scale_y_continuous("bpm", breaks= c(40,55,70,85,100,115))
c

#Flip the boxplot horizontally
d<- c + coord_flip()
d

# Move tick inward and erase x axis
e<-d + theme(
  axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"), 
  axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")),
  axis.text.y = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")),
  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_blank()
)
```

Comment: Does it work without `theme_tufte`? I tried the code (on random numbers, since I couldn't find `Pulse.rate.2020`) and my plot has no "x" on the left axis. (Truthfully, I did not use `geom_rangeframe()` either.)

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following for the last chunk solved the problem for me:

```
e<-d + theme(
  axis.ticks.length.x=unit(-0.25, "cm"), 
  axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")),
  axis.text.y = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")),
  axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "cm")
) + labs(x="")
```

[image]